# Merge int's into a single int in C#

Tags: c#, merge

I have:

```
int a = 9;
int b = 7;
int c = 3;
```

How to merge those so it becomes int d = 973; ?
The only thing i managed to come up with is:

```
string merge = $"{a}{b}{c}";
int d = Int32.Parse(merge);
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: _d = (a*100)+(b*10)+c;_ But perhaps you should explain what are you really trying to solve instead of fixing on an idea. It seems a case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can try to merge like this: `string merge = a + "" + b + c;`

Comment: Your ways is good enough in my opinion.

Comment: @zzT  OP already did a string merger. He was asking for something more efficient. But I agree with Steve. This sure looks like an XY Problem

Comment: Well they give me 3 separate integers a,b,c and i need to do couple of checks for each combination from abc to 111. And according to the result of the checks i need to add/subtract/multiply a specific value to a given "special" integer. And i need to stop when that "special" integer becomes equal or greater than another "control" integer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [Linq's Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
var input = new[] { a, b, c };

var number = input.Aggregate((t, c) => t * 10 + c);
```

This multiplies the total by 10 and adds the current number for each number in the input sequence.

Iteratively you'd write it like this:

```
var number = 0;
foreach (var i in input)
{
    number = number * 10 + i;
}
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Note that both approaches are prone to integer overflow.